# Calling function which has no permission from another function

Tags: postgresql, function, permissions

Say we have two functions. First should check permissions and if all goes right update table. Here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.clients_test(
_clientid int
,_comments varchar
)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare _result varchar;
BEGIN

if now()::time>'17:00'::time then
    select public.clients_check_17_00() into _result;
end if;

update clients set comments=_comments where clientid=_clientid;

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 1;
ALTER FUNCTION public.clients_test(int, varchar) OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.clients_test(int, varchar) TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.clients_test(int, varchar) TO "RestrictedAccess";
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.clients_test(int, varchar) FROM public;
```

Second function doing nothing with database and exists only for security reasons. I was going to call it from the fist one. Here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.clients_check_17_00()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 1;
ALTER FUNCTION public.clients_check_17_00()OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.clients_check_17_00() TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.clients_check_17_00() TO "FullAccess";
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.clients_check_17_00() FROM public;
```

Some users should have to update comments only before 17:00. So they have permissions on

```
public.clients_test
```

and have no permissions on

```
public.clients_check_17_00
```

I'd like to have the error 'You do not have permissions to execute public.clients_check_17_00', but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem, but your approach is all wrong.

Rather than checking for the time *inside* the function, you should manipulate permissions *outside* of the function. In your approach, the time is checked on every call, also at 08:02, 14:23, 16:34, etc, which is very inefficient for the obvious reasons. Instead, make two simple SQL script files, one to disable execute permissions on the function and another to enable those permissions again and have a scheduled job run those scripts at 17:00 and then presumably at 08:00 or so to re-enable execute permission. It could be as simple as:

```
psql -h localhost -d your_db -U postgres \
     -c 'REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION clients_test(int, varchar) FROM "RestrictedAccess"'
```

And vice-versa for enabling the permission again. But see the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) for parameters specific to accessing your server.

How exactly that works depends on your OS; in Linux you would use a `cron` job, on Windows you use Task Scheduler.

Incidentally, returning a message from a function to the session is done with `RAISE NOTICE`.

Another important point from your code: **NEVER USE THE postgres ROLE AS OWNER OF OBJECTS OR TO RUN CODE**. Apologies for **EMPHASIS** but this point can not be stressed enough. You should instead make a non-privileged role, preferably without `login` privilege, as owner of all objects (tables and functions, etc) and then explicitly set privileges for specific user roles.

Comment: Hi, Patrick. Thank you for your suggestion. It was stupid for me to simplify original problem. In fact I have some records in a table which I tried to separate by the age. For example records older then 24 hours could not be edited by "RestrictedAccess" group. So when someone tried to edit record I was checking if 24 hours are gone and if yes tried to execute function.

Comment: I use postgres as owner of objects because I using function with "security definer" flag. So users have no permissions to direct modify tables or select data from them. Users can only execute functions and functions make very limited modifications. Near one function per field. So I can fine tune permissions. Am I understand you right that even now I have to replace postgres with something else?

Comment: Tables are by default only accessible to their owner (and superusers) and the owner has full permissions. So even if the owning role has no significant other permissions, or even login privilege, it fully controls the tables. You do not need a supervisor role for that.